React not setting cookie correctly, cant get cookie from a component
I'm fairly confused. I'm setting a cookie in my profilesApi.ts file (it manages all the endpoints of my profiles app). This is the code:
async function setCsrfToken() {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get(`/profiles/get_csrf_token/`);
    console.log('Response from CSRF token endpoint:', response.data);
    const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    console.log('CSRF token retrieved from cookies:', csrftoken);
    if (csrftoken) {
      axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken'] = csrftoken;
      console.log('CSRF token set in axios instance');
      console.log('CSRF just set:', axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken']);
    } else {
      console.error('No CSRF token found in cookies');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error initializing CSRF token:', error);
  }
}

This code correctly logs the csrf token:
Response from CSRF token endpoint: {message: 'CSRF cookie set'}
profilesApi.ts:30 CSRF token retrieved from cookies: 0tChouzkTCx3sI86M9HQg9kbm5Lvfr1L
profilesApi.ts:33 CSRF token set in axios instance
profilesApi.ts:34 CSRF just set: 0tChouzkTCx3sI86M9HQg9kbm5Lvfr1L

However, in my Login component I try to retrieve the cookie to make sure its being sent in a form.
const Login = () => {
const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState({username: '', password: ''});
const navigate = useNavigate();
useEffect(() => {
    const initializeCsrf = () => {
        setCsrfToken().then(() => {
            console.log('CSRF token on Login load:', axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken']);
        });
    };
    initializeCsrf();
}, []);

it logs "undefined". I thought it was a timing issue so I created a button that would log the csrf_token in the header:
const logCsrfToken = () => {
    console.log('CSRF token:', axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRFToken']);
};

clicking the button also logs undefined. So, the cookie arrives correctly, then is set correctly in the profilesApi but when doing so from the Login component it just isn't there.
Which is the correct way to set a csrf token (found in a cookie) in the headers? I'm missing something obvious, however the IA is also clueless.

Two possibilities. 1) Something else touches axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common in some other file. 2) You're not using the same axios instance. Can often be inadvertently triggered by symlinks, mismatching versions and such. Can you show where you import axiosInstance in both Logon and profilesApi.ts, and the file that exports it? Is this a multi-package setup? Is the login component and and profilesApi.ts in the same npm package?

Use axios Interceptors to set tokens before making the request. export axios instance and use that instance.
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.use(
    function (config) {
        // Do something before request is sent
        return config
    },
    function (error) {
        // Do something with request error
        return Promise.reject(error)
    }
)

export default axiosInstance

Check official documentation.
